# Ubuntu 20.04 rtl8192ee

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

Apologies, this is another wifi connection question.
The best way to describe the wifi connection is 'unpredictable'. It occasionally works fine; at other times, it is extremely slow, and there are intermittent disconnects that subsequently request authorisation.

Installed the latest Ubuntu: 20.04. The main issue (besides openCL, amd gpu and Blender, but that is another story) is the wifi connection.

$lspci

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
07:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

$iwconfig:

```
wlp7s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"[network name]"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: [Access point]  
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:450   Missed beacon:0
```

$uname -r:

```
5.4.0-29-generic
```

$nmcli device status:

```
DEVICE          TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION  
wlp7s0          wifi      connected     [network name] 
p2p-dev-wlp7s0  wifi-p2p  disconnected  --          
enp3s0          ethernet  unavailable   --          
lo              loopback  unmanaged     --
```

I have tried:

i) Setting power save to off (as can be seen in return for iwconfig)

ii) Installing drivers from lwfinger/rtlwifi_new (not sure that this had much hope, but tried it anyway)

iii) removing backport-iwlwifi-dkms package: `sudo apt remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms' (not installed, anyway)

iv) editing '/etc/gai.conf' and uncommenting the line with '::ffff:0:0/96  100' (wifi no longer worked, at all)

v) Looking for additional drivers in "Software and Updates" (no additional drivers available)

(I am currently waiting for my wifi to come back on to post this!...; anytime, now...)

Comment: Since I updated to 20.04, I have exactly this problem.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution. I switched to Manjaro, and had the same problem with that distro. I then tried a different adapter which, it turned out, had the same chipset as the other adapter. I finally bought a new wifi adapter (AWP1200E), which uses a different chipset, but, again, weak connection. I have been using Linux for quite some time, and tolerated a lot of the "compatibility issues"; unfortunately, I think I am going to have to bite the bullet and switch to Windows (spent too much money on my setup to have a partially working machine!)...

Answer (score 3):

I have a Lenovo T440s with that wireless card. I cloned and built this https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192ee, the directions in the README were very good. It didn't work when I built with the makefile, but using dkms did the trick. Also note that I did not have a 50-blacklist.conf file, I put the entry in blacklist.conf, granted I dont really know the difference, it seemed to work either way. Connection seems to be more reliable now.

Comment: This module worked for me. For others trying, rather than using `sudo make install`, you can use the checkinstall package: install with `sudo apt install checkinstall`, run with `sudo checkinstall` and accept the default options. This creates a deb file and installs it, which means it's much easier to uninstall and clean up should you need to.

Comment: It doesn't matter that 50-blacklist.conf doesn't exist; any file in /etc/modprobe.d is read, and the command in the readme will create it if it doesn't exist. If you want to try out the module before editing the config files, you can just do `sudo modprobe -r rtl8192ee` followed by `sudo modprobe 8192ee` and `sudo systemctl restart network-manager`. This will take effect immediately, but revert on next boot.